# Can't log in to Ask Ubuntu from my new computer - works fine on the old one

Tags: support, login

I tried to connect to Ask Ubuntu on my new computer but my email and password in the Login Mask just "froze" and nothing happened, I then tried the forgotten password business and received an email from you but after changing the password to the same one it didn't change anything either.

Now I'm on my old computer and all is well!

What's the secret to changing accounts on computers please?
Can I keep my account on both old and new computer?

Thanks for any info.

...also why am I "mysterious" or something to that effect" on your Ask Ubuntu site?

Comment: Try it again please!

Comment: to answer your second question - I assume you haven't filled in the "About Me" section under ["Edit profile and settings"](https://askubuntu.com/users/edit/667922) (link will work when you're logged in!)

Answer (score 5):

The "secret" to changing accounts on computers is that Firefox has a master password + sync feature that enables syncing website passwords across all your devices with the website passwords protected by the Firefox master password.

To sync Firefox Quantum versions 57 and later follow [these steps](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1214940):

1. Login to Firefox with your master password.
2. Click the 3-bar toolbar button (labeled **Open menu** on cursor hover) in the upper right corner of Firefox.
3. A dual-circular arrow appears to the right of that email address, which will "spin" when Firefox is communicating with the Sync server. That "dual-circular arrow " also serves as a button for doing a manual sync event; upon cursor hover that "button" will show the Day and Time of the last sync event, either automatic or manual.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know I had a Firefox Master Password, and I didn't. I now created one and after toying around for a bit .... me voila !! Thanks again for the info, I do log in quite often to search and read. As I am a DIY sort of person Ask Ubuntu is a godsend. - Kind Regards - Garoolgan

Comment: @Garoolgan If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.